# How can I create bi-directional mappings with MyBatis 3.0.5?

Tags: mybatis

Say I have two domain objects and a mapper interface.

```java
class Person {
    int id;
    List<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<Problem>();
}

class Problem {
    int id;
    Person person;
}

interface PersonMapper {
    public List<Person> selectAllPersons();
}
```

And two database tables.

```sql
create table person (
    id integer not null generated always as identity constraint person_pk primary key,
)

create table problem (
    id integer not null generated always as identity constraint problem_pk primary key,
    person_id integer not null constraint problem_person_fk references person
)
```

I can create a mapping file that gets the data I want.

```xml
<resultMap id="personMap" type="Person">
    <id column="person_id" property="id" />
    <collection column="problem_person_id" property="problems"
                javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Problem" resultMap="problemMap" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="problemMap" type="Problem">
    <id column="problem_id" property="id" />
    <!-- Adding an association here will cause a circular dependency -->
    <!-- The circular dependency results in a StackOverflowException -->
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAllPersons" resultMap="personMap">
    select
        person.id as person_id,
        problem.id as problem_id
    from person left outer join problem on person.id = problem.person_id
</select>
```

However, since MyBatis doesn't do bi-directional mapping, none of the `Problem` objects in the returned collections will have their `Person` reference set correctly.

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=322), it sounds like I should be able to update my mapper interface and add a custom result handler that can be supplied by the calling class.

```java
interface PersonMapper {
    public List<Person> selectAllPersons(ResultHandler handler);
}

class PersonResultHandler implements ResultHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
        System.out.println(context.getResultObject());
    }
}

class PersonDAO {
    // Get SqlSession sqlSession
    sqlSession.getMapper(PersonMapper.class).selectAllPersons(new PersonResultHandler());
}
```

However, the `handleResult` method of my `ResultHandler` never gets called.  I've seen [this example](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/ResultHandlerExample), but the extra fluff class in there makes it very difficult to understand.  Can anyone give me a simple example of using a custom `ResultHandler` with mapper interfaces?  I'm using MyBatis 3.0.5+.

I've also read through the MyBatis mailing list and there are several suggestions of using caching and lazy loading to solve circular dependencies, but I can't find any examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your method declaration to:

```java
interface PersonMapper {
    public void selectAllPersons(ResultHandler handler);
}
```

And populate `List<Person>` inside your `PersonResultHandler`

```java
class PersonResultHandler implements ResultHandler {

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
        Object result = context.getResultObject();
        if (result instanceof Person) {
            Person person = (Person) result;
            for (Problem problem : person.getProblems()) {
                problem.setPerson(person);
            }
            persons.add(person);
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }
}
```